# adding an object element to an immutable array(javascript)

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, immutability

I'm working with redux and I have some issues on how to insert an object into an element of the state in an immutable manner.
I have this type of state

```
   const Initial_State={
    filmList:[],
    title:'',
    description:'',
}
export default (state = Initial_State, action) => {
    const {PUSH,POP,CLEAR,SELECT}=ListKeys
    switch(action){
        case PUSH://need code to insert an object into filmlist
```

Comment: You create a new array, e.g. `[...filmList, newEntry]`. See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911194/how-do-i-add-an-element-to-array-in-reducer-of-react-native-redux) for Redux-specific details.

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=redux+add+to+array) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Also, please follow the official tutorials. You are writing a very outdated style of redux here. Modern redux, applied correctly (createSlice), does the immutability thing for you so you can just push into your array "mutably" when using it.

Comment: forgot the link: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: ty very much guys